# Best practice for storing a 64 bit hash in a SQL Database

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, database-design

How would you efficiently store a 64 bit hash value in a SQL DB (SQL Server 2008) using C#/Entity Framework?  More specifically, what data type would you use to store the hash value in the DB and how would you convert the original hash to/from the value?

The original hash value is being computed and stored in a BitArray:

```
BitArray hash = CalculateHashValue(); // Returns a BitArray(64)
```

One option to store this has value would be to use a data type of binary(64).  I could then add the hash to the DB using the following:

```
byte[] hashAsByteArray = new byte[8];
dhash.CopyTo(hashAsByteArray, 0);

MyDbObject mdo = new MyDbObject();
mdo.hash = hashAsByteArray;
db.MyDbObject.AddObject(mdo);
db.SaveChanges();
```

The resulting value stored in the DB from this option appears to have a lot of 0's padded at the end which doesn't look to be an efficient use of space (e.g. 0x0CAA0820848200800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000)

What are some better approaches you would use?  Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for `varbinary(64)` instead of `binary(64)`?

Comment: `binary(64)` is 64 bytes, not 64 bits. Try `binary(8)`.

Comment: Why not use a `varchar(max)` and convert it from and to base64?

Comment: If you will always have 64-bits and don't mind the signed/unsigned inconvenience you can use [bigint](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187745.aspx?ppud=4) on the database side and [Int64](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int64.aspx) in C#. EF is bound to provide some _value add_ to something that simple.

Comment: Thanks for the responses.  Ended up going with binary(8) and works like a charm.